# Why can't I disable a button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, interaction

I have a problem. Every time I try to make a non-interactable button with Button.Interactable
But for some reason I do not understand it does not work. My code is very simple:

```
public Button boton1, boton2;

bool boton1Bool, boton2Bool;

void Start()
{
    boton1 = GetComponent<Button>();
    boton2 = GetComponent<Button>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (boton1Bool == true) {

        Debug.Log("BOTON 1");
        boton2.interactable = false;
    }
    else if (boton1Bool == false) {

        boton2.interactable = true;
    }

    if (boton2Bool == true) {

        Debug.Log("BOTON 2");
        boton1.interactable = false;
    }
    else if (boton2Bool == false) {

        boton1.interactable = true;
    }
}

public void Boton1Down(){

    boton1Bool = true;
}

public void Boton1Up()
{
    boton1Bool = false;
}

public void Boton2Down(){

    boton2Bool = true;
}

public void Boton2Up()
{

    boton2Bool = false;
}
```

What this small program does is apply Button.Intaractable = false, to a button pressed the other. Simple.
I also leave screenshots of the buttons along with their respective scripts:

[image]

[image]

Now I have the following code, but it still does not disable the button that I do not press:

´´´

```
public Button boton1, boton2;

void Update()
{
    
}

public void Boton1Down(){

    boton2.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
}

public void Boton1Up()
{
    boton2.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;


}

public void Boton2Down(){

    boton1.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
}

public void Boton2Up()
{
    boton1.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
}
```

´´´

Comment: Can you tell me why you use `Update()` method for enabling/disabling buttons? Simply you can enable and disable them in the `ButtonDown()` and `ButtonUp()` methods. Also, there's problem in initializing the `button1` and `button2` in the `Start()` method.

Comment: The code that I posted, disabled the other button when you press the mouse and when you release it, enabled the button again. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I need that.

Comment: How did you find the other button disabled when you click on a button?

Comment: Assign the respective buttons on the inspector, make sure of it, but it still does not work as it should.

Comment: What the program should do is disable a button when the other is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in initializing `boton1` and `boton2`:

```cs
boton1 = GetComponent<Button>();
boton2 = GetComponent<Button>();
```

The two above lines mean that the `boton1` and `boton2` are the same and refer to the button that is attached to the GameObject.

No need to initialize them in the `Start()` method. Because you made them public and set them in the **Inspector** panel. So, remove the `Start()` method.

Also, no need to use `Update()` method and some `bool` variables in your code. Instead, remove `Update()` and `bool` vars and change `BotonUp()` and `BotonDown()` methods:

```cs
public void Boton1Down()
{
    boton2.interactable = false;
}

public void Boton1Up()
{
    boton2.interactable = true;
}

public void Boton2Down()
{
    boton1.interactable = false;
}

public void Boton2Up()
{
    boton1.interactable = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in a previous answer, the way you're assigning value to boton1 and boton2 leads to failure.

You need to assign them in the **Inspector**. Since you are making these variables ***public***, they will have a field there to be assigned.

Btw, I'll give you a more complete solution:

- Divide your code into two components:

  - One to assign to your gameObject who has the Button component
  - Other to substitute the button controller you shared here

The first component will look like this:

```
// Attach this to the game objects with the button component
public ButtonHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public UnityEvent onStopClick = new UnityEvent();
    public UnityEvent onClick = new UnityEvent();
    
    private void Start()
    {
        var btn = GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(onClick.Invoke);
    }
    
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        onStopClick.Invoke();
    }
}
```

With this, you'll have information when you click the button and when you release the button.

And to substitute your controller, you can use this:

```
// Assign this on Unity Editor
public ButtonHandler boton1, boton2;

void Start()
{
    boton1.onClick.AddListener(Boton1Down);
    boton1.onStopClick.AddListener(Boton1Up);
    boton2.ocClick.AddListener(Boton2Down);
    boton2.onStopClick.AddListener(Boton2Up);
}

public void Boton1Down()
{
    boton2.interactable = false;
}

public void Boton1Up()
{
    boton2.interactable = true;
}

public void Boton2Down()
{
    boton1.interactable = false;
}

public void Boton2Up()
{
     boton1.interactable = true;
}
```

Remember: assign the ButtonHandler objects using the **Inspector** tab in the **Editor**.